# Does Spring framework supports propagation of transaction contexts across osgi calls?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, osgi

I have methods annotated with @Transactional in different OSGI bundles. All the bundles usages it's own transaction manager provided by spring. Now, if I call methodA() and methodB() in the bundle3 using OSGI reference of bundle1 and bundle2, will it be covered under single transaction? So, if methodB() fails, methodA() should be rolled back?

Bundle1

```
 class ServiceA {
    @Transactional
    public void methodA() {
       ..........
    }
}
```

Bundle2

```
class ServiceB {
    @Transactional
    public void methodB() {
       ..........
    }
}
```

Bundle3

```
 class ServiceC {
    @Autowired
    Bundle1 b1;

    @Autowired
    Bundle2 b2;

    @Transactional
    public void methodC() {
           b1.methodA();
           b2.methodB();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses a thread local to store the transaction context. As OSGi service calls use the same thread I think the transaction should be propagated.